# position absolute & margin bottom

Tags: css, position, margin, absolute, margins

I have this container which is absolutely positioned .. The problem with it is I can't give it a margin bottom value !!

I want no matter how much content inside that green container .. I want the next div (under) to be under it with 30px always

I can't do that and I don't know why !

http://jsfiddle.net/nxFkG/54/

html

```
<div class="bg-black">
    <div class="bg-green">
        <ul>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="under">
    <h1>THIS SHOULD BE UNDER THE GREEN CONTAINER NO MATTER HOW MUCH THE CONTENT INSIDE IT</h1>
</div>
```

css

```
.bg-black {
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
}
.bg-green {
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom:163px;
}
```

Any help on how to do it & why it happend !!

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look can be achieved with a simple gradient.

- Remove the absolute positioning (which essentially makes the element invisible to other elements) and remove the parents height
- Use a linear gradient with the desired colour stops, including `transparent`

#### Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.bg-black {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 120px, transparent 120px);
  width: 160px;
}
.bg-green {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-black">
  <div class="bg-green">
    <ul>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="under">
  <h1>Under the green container</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from normal flow and cannot affect elements that are in normal flow.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but what is the solution in this case ? some will add more content than the others !!

Comment: @Jobter Don't use absolute positioning for elements that should affect next elements. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nxFkG/55/).

Comment: It's for the look & design's sake ... nothing to go around this ?!!

Comment: Some picture would probably be helpful as for what you intend to achieve.